# How to write this function in functional style in python?

Tags: python, algorithm, functional-programming

There is a function written structurally in python that implements Dijkstra's algorithm. I need to write it in a functional style, but I never wrote functionally. Tell me how to do it.
Here is my code:

```py
_adj_list = {'A': {'B': 5}}  # vertex adjacency list (e.g. AB = 5)

# the current parameter is the vertex, where to find the shortest paths to all other vertices
# returns the visited dictionary (the result of the algorithm)
def algorithm_dijkstra(current):
    nodes = tuple(_adj_list.keys())

    unvisited = {node: None for node in nodes}
    visited = {}
    current_distance = 0
    unvisited[current] = current_distance

    while True:
        try:
            for neighbour, distance in _adj_list[current].items():
                if neighbour not in unvisited:
                    continue
                new_distance = current_distance + distance
                if unvisited[neighbour] is None or unvisited[neighbour] > new_distance:
                    unvisited[neighbour] = new_distance
            visited[current] = current_distance
            del unvisited[current]
            if not unvisited:
                break
            candidates = [node for node in unvisited.items() if node[1]]
            current, current_distance = sorted(candidates, key=lambda x: x[1])[0]
        except LookupError:
            for key in unvisited:
                visited[key] = 'no way'
            unvisited.clear()
            break

    return visited
```

Comment: It's a very broad question. Dijkstra's algorithm is a poor fit for functional style (as is python), and a good solution will be quite a lot of code that looks not much like the imperative version you have in a question. I suggest you find a functional version of dijkstra in a functional programming language, and transliterate it into python.

Comment: @PaulHankin I can’t implement it in this way on Python and find it too. I think I will follow your advice, although I'm sure this will not be an easy task either.
But one more question. I have such a task that I need to write a module with 4-5 methods in a functional style on Python. I chose the graph and Dijkstra's algorithm, which was a mistake. Can you advise what is better to write? Maybe you know links to something like that. I just lost a lot of time on this.

Comment: Use Bellman-Ford instead, implementing it as the matrix multiplication over the [tropical semiring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tropical_semiring) in map-reduce style.

Comment: @phipsgabler, hello again. A lot of time has passed, but I still can’t get functional python programming. I saw your status that you like this style of programming, so I am writing here again, but specifically to you. Please help me deal with this. I already found the algorithm on erlang, but again the problem is - I can not rewrite it to python. If you are ready to help, then we would continue the dialogue right here.

Comment: Do the following: translate your algorithm as far as you get, and then ask a new question with both the Erlang and your Python attempt, and you reqirements. People are much more likely to answer that.